# Use === to check whether String.replace() actually performed a substitution?

Tags: javascript, string, replace, equality

I'd like to know whether `String.replace()` actually found a match and performed a substitution.  Since `String.replace()` returns the resulting string rather than the number of substitutions performed, it seems that I would have to compare the original with the result.

The question is, should I use `===` or `==` for that comparison?

As far as I can tell, neither the [Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) nor the [ECMAScript 5.1 Standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.5.4.11) specifies that the string that is returned must be the same object as the string that was passed in, if no match occurred.

On the other hand, it would seem stupid for any implementation of JavaScript to return a copy of an unchanged string.

In concrete terms, what happens with

```
var s = 'abc';
var t = s.replace(/d/, 'D');
console.log(s === t);     // I expect true, but am not sure
```

Is it

1. Guaranteed to print `true`?  If so, where is that behaviour documented?
2. Undefined and unreliable behaviour (i.e., I should test `s == t` instead, or do something clever with a replacement callback closure)?
3. Undefined behaviour that in practice returns `true` on every JavaScript implementation?

### Edit

@cookiemonster asks:

> So it seems that you're not really wondering if the result is guaranteed, but more whether an implementation is optimized to perform an identity comparison internally. Is that right?

Actually, I did screw up the question, and it ended up being an X-Y problem.  What I *really* want to know is, how can I check whether any substitution occurred (the actual number of substitutions doesn't matter — one or more times are all the same)?  And do so efficiently, without doing a separate `.match()` or a character-by-character comparison.  And be certain that the result is guaranteed by the language specification.

Comment: I would simply try both and find out...

Comment: Also, if you want to know how many replacements will be made, use `String.match(/d/g)`

Comment: Alex: If no match occurred, why would it matter if the original or a new string is returned? It would have no impact on the comparison done by `==` and `===`.

Comment: @BenTaber `String.match(/d/g).length` :)

Comment: @barakmanos Trying won't help me distinguish between cases 1, 2, and 3.

Comment: @cookiemonster I'm trying to avoid a character-by-character check for equality, as well as a redundant test for `.match()`.

Comment: So it seems that you're not really wondering if the result is guaranteed, but more whether an implementation is optimized to perform an identity comparison internally. Is that right?

Comment: ...let me put it this way. An affirmative answer to your question abouve *(the result being guaranteed `true`)* doesn't necessarily imply that the engine will perform a character by character comparison. It could very well be optimized to avoid such a comparison when it can guarantee that the string hasn't changed.

Comment: While I don't know if it's a worthwhile optimization, one option would be to perform an `.indexOf()` search on the string to see if it returned `-1`, and if not, do a `.replace()` on a substring starting at the index that was returned, and add that resulting string to a slice of the first part of the string. `str.slice(0, idx) + str.slice(idx).replace("foo", "bar");` Now you're only building a new string when you know there was a match. However you'd need to do some performance testing on long strings to see if it actually improves anything, or perhaps makes it worse.

Comment: Where the Type of both values is the same, it doesn't matter if you use `===` or `==`. In this case the comparison is two string primitives, so it doesn't matter which is used. [*Replace*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.5.4.11) always returns a new string, even if no replacement is made, it doesn't modify the original string.

Comment: @RobG: An engine could be optimized to avoid the creation of a new string when no replacement is needed. This is a pretty common optimization in languages that have immutable strings.

Comment: @cookiemonster—maybe they do, but they can't **appear** to do that, they have to behave as if they made a new string. Otherwise, they aren't compliant with ECMA-262.

Comment: @RobG: I agree, but the reason they can often do such optimizations is because of the fact that strings are immutable. As we use primitive strings in our apps, there's no capacity for us to alter them in any way, so we can never know at any point if we're working with the original or a copy, which works to the benefit of the  implementation in this regard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`===` won't work with a `String` object:

```
a = new String("foo")
a.replace(/XXX/, "") == a
> true
a.replace(/XXX/, "") === a
> false
```

or any object that has a custom `toString` method:

```
b  = { toString: function() { return "foo" }}
"foo".replace(/XXX/, "") == b
> true
"foo".replace(/XXX/, "") === b
> false
```

Most of the time, this is a non-issue, but "praemonitus, praemunitus" as they say.

To answer your update: as seen [here](https://code.google.com/p/v8/codesearch#v8/trunk/src/runtime.cc&l=4082), at least V8 is optimized to return the subject itself if no replacements can be made:

```
  int32_t* current_match = global_cache.FetchNext();
  if (current_match == NULL) {
    if (global_cache.HasException()) return isolate->heap()->exception();
    return *subject; <-------
```

and, although the [standard](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.6) only requires two strings to *look* the same to be strict equal (`===`), I'm absolutely positive that every JS engine out there is smart enough to avoid strcmp on equal pointers.

Comment: This is so far the only answer that underlines the caveat of string objects and string primitives. +1

Comment: @stevuu: Well, the question seems pretty specific to the example provided, but I guess the information here is still worth noting.

Answer (score 3):

It makes no difference.

Why? Because `String.replace` operates on strings, and returns a string. Also, strings are primitives, *not* objects.

You *already know* that you have two strings. `==` and `===` are therefore identical for this purpose. I'd even go so far as to say that `===` is superfluous.

Comment: "Strings are primitives, not objects." is true for the given example, but not always so. There are string primitives and string objects, and they are _not_ the same.

Comment: @stevuu Was just about to post the same thing. The way most people use strings, they are primitives, but when invoking the string constructor, objects are returned.

Comment: "The way most people use strings…"—does anyone use String objects instead of primitives?

Answer (score 2):

Given your example...

> *"Is it Guaranteed to print true? If so, where is that behaviour documented?"*

Yes, it is. It's documented in the respective equality comparison algorithms used by `==` and `===`.

- [Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm](http://es5.github.io/#x11.9.3)
- [Strict Equality Comparison Algorithm](http://es5.github.io/#x11.9.6)

> *"Is it Undefined and unreliable behaviour (i.e., I should test s == t instead, or do something clever with a replacement callback closure)?"*

No, it's well defined behavior. See above. The `==` and `===` operators will behave identically.

> *"Is it Undefined behaviour that in practice returns true on every JavaScript implementation?"*

As long an implementation is following the specification, it will return `true`.

Answer (score 1):

The `replace` method on the String class always returns a string, so `===` is just as safe to use and reliable as `==` since no type coercion will happen. Secondly, if no substitution occurred, the `===` test will return true since they contain the same characters.